# Notation for a placeholder function that maps to other functions

Tags: notation

I'm trying to write a very general equation to calculate some $Value$ which relies on a context-dependent function $g$.

How do I concisely communicate that $g$ maps to different functions under different  contexts?

So far I have:

\begin{gather}
&\text{Value (a, b, c)} = {g(a,b)} + 10\\
\
\text{where:}&\\
g \mapsto\\
& A(i,j) = \begin{cases}
 1 ,& \text{if some condition}\\
 0 ,& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}\\
\nonumber\
& B(i,j) = \begin{cases}
 1 ,& \text{if some condition}\\
 0 ,& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}\\
\nonumber
& C(i,j) = \begin{cases}
 1 ,& \text{if some condition}\\
 0 ,& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}\\
\nonumber
\end{gather}

Answer (score 3):

The  *[Iverson    brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)*   could be useful    in this   case. Let $P$ be a proposition. We write
\begin{align*}
[[P]]=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad  \text{if $P$ is true}\\
0&\qquad \text{if $P$ is false}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

> This way we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> g(a,b)=A(a,b)[[X(a,b)]]+B(a,b)[[Y(a,b)]]+C(a,b)[[Z(a,b)]]
> \end{align*}

Comment: Interesting, never seen that before -- but I'm not sure I can use it in the way that I want. I'm trying to emphasize that A B C map directly to g with full mutual exclusivity

Comment: @tetris11: This aspect is not part of your question. So, you mean $\max_{a,b}\left\{[[X(a,b)]]+[[Y(a,b)]]+[[Z(a,b)]]\right\}=1$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No not exactly, X Y and Z are just random statements - I would ignore them entirely (I just put them in order to give context to the $g$ parameters. I've modified my original question.

Comment: what I'm really trying to say is "$g$ maps directly to one of A, or B, or C depending on some parameter (say $c$)". I hope that's a little clearer